# Within the standard JavaScript ES6 environment, when is .toString() ever called?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tostring

I only found that the time `.toString()` is called is with string concatenation and string interpolation:

```
// Inside of Node:

> let arr = [1,3,5];

> arr.toString()
'1,3,5'

> "" + arr
'1,3,5'

> arr + ""
'1,3,5'

> `${arr}`
'1,3,5'
```

Supposedly, `console.log` prints out the string representation of the object and is supposed to use `toString()`, but I am not sure whether it is `toString()` not properly implemented usually, so `console.log` does something else:

```
> console.log(arr);
[ 1, 3, 5 ]

> console.log("arr is %s", arr);
arr is [ 1, 3, 5 ]
```

So inside the JavaScript itself, when is `toString()` ever called?

I think by polymorphism, anything we write ourselves, we can use `ourObj.toString()` to get the string representation of our object as string. But I wonder within JavaScript itself (all its function, libraries, classes), when is `toString()` actually invoked?

Comment: `document.write` uses `toString()` for non-string objects.

Comment: It is called whenever a string is expected and valueOf is NOT defined.

Comment: "*Supposedly, `console.log` prints out the string representation of the object*" - no. Why do you think it did? Which particular `console` are you thinking of (there are many implementations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In several sections of the EcmaScript language specification, there is mention of `toString`. One important use occurs in the abstract operation [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ordinarytoprimitive): this function will look for the object's `toString` or `valueOf` method, and execute it. The precedence can be influenced by a *hint* argument.

In turn, `OrdinaryToPrimitive` is called by the abstract operation [`ToPrimitive`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)

`ToPrimitive` is called by `ToNumber`, `ToString`, `ToPropertyKey`, relational comparison, equality comparison, evaluation of expressions, the `Date` constructor, several stringification methods, like `toJSON`, ...etc.

In fact, the language is soaked with internal operations that will get to executing `ToPrimitive`. The specification has 200+ references to `ToString`.

#### Examples

Here is a object with a `toString` method implementation in order to prove that `toString` is called internally.

Then follow a few expressions that each trigger `toString`.

```js
// Preparation
let obj = {
    toString() {
        this.i = (this.i||0) + 1; // counter
        console.log("call #" + this.i);
        return "0";
    }
};

// Trigger toString via several constructs
({})[obj];
1 < obj; 
1 == obj;
1 + obj;
1 - obj;
+obj;
Math.abs(obj);
parseInt(obj);
new Date(obj);
new RegExp(obj);
new Number(obj);
Symbol(obj); 
"".localeCompare(obj);
[obj, null].sort();
[obj].join();
`${obj}`;
setTimeout(obj); // Not standard EcmaScript environment, but defined in the agent.
```

Some of these would not trigger `toString()` if there were a `valueOf` method defined on `obj` which would return a primitive value.

Comment: do you think perhaps you can give a couple of actual example occurrences of `toString()` being called?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Indeed. There are many, many more: `new Function(obj)`, `~obj`, `obj|0`, `""+obj`, ...

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate some perhaps more common cases:

1. String interpolation (probably most useful)
2. String addition or concatenation
3. Creation of a symbol or string
4. As a property key
5. Used by `Array`'s `join()`

Inside of Node console:

```
> let foo = { a: 123, toString: function() { return `an object with value ${this.a}`; } };

> foo
{ a: 123, toString: [Function: toString] }

> foo.toString()
'an object with value 123'

> foo.a = 456;
456

> foo.toString()
'an object with value 456'

> `${foo}`
'an object with value 456'

> "foo: " + foo
'foo: an object with value 456'

> "foo: ".concat(foo)
'foo: an object with value 456'

> let d = {};

> d[foo] = "hello";
'hello'

> d
{ 'an object with value 456': 'hello' }

> Symbol(foo)
Symbol(an object with value 456)

> String(foo)
'an object with value 456'

> let bar = Object.assign({}, foo);   // clone

> bar.a = 789;
789

> [foo, bar].join(" - ")
'an object with value 456 - an object with value 789'
```