# In JavaScript ES6, if console.log() doesn't invoke obj.toString(), what does it use?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Some related info is in this question: [Within the standard JavaScript ES6 environment, when is .toString() ever called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435952/within-the-standard-javascript-es6-environment-when-is-tostring-ever-called)

By polymorphism, `toString()` is the standard message to send to the object (or the standard method to invoke on the object), by the interface of the Object class.

But obviously, `console.log()` doesn't use it:

```
// Inside of Node

> let aSet = new Set([1,3,5]);

> aSet.toString()
'[object Set]'

> console.log(aSet);
Set { 1, 3, 5 }

> let aMap = new Map([["foo", 1], ["bar", 2]])

> aMap.toString()
'[object Map]'

> console.log(aMap)
Map { 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2 }
```

so what does `console.log()` use?  It is not `valueOf()`, as `valueOf()` just returns the object itself in this case, when no primitive value is available.

It'd be quite ugly to "special case" what class it is, and perform different actions -- as polymorphism, having the standard "verb", in this case `toString()`, is what is supposed to be used. To find out what the class is and perform different actions (such as using a switch statement), is exactly what we don't want to do in OOP.

Comment: It uses native code (not written in Javascript - I think C++ for V8). This native code *may* invoke `toString`, but it's implementation-dependent, I think

Comment: @CertainPerformance is `console` part of v8? I thought every environments had to make their own.

Comment: Most web consoles definitely do "special case" treatment based on the value to be printed in the console, and I don't see what's "ugly" about that. What the console is supposed to do is to give **me** something **I** can read in order to know what's that value I tried to log.

Comment: JS has come a long way. `console.log` really should use `toString()` and the `Set` and `Map` class should really define a good `toString()`. Unless, it is due to backward compatibility that `Array` is not doing the proper thing and if corrected, it may break code out there every where. Special casing each class is exactly what is not supposed to be done in OOP.

Comment: @nopole - I disagree. What consoles do works well, particularly live consoles (when you realize you're dealing with a live console). It's easy enough, if you want a string, to do that yourself when making the call (perhaps with a helper method for things like Maps and Sets). But anyway, SO isn't about what "should" be, it's about what "is." :-)

Comment: @nopole But `console` is not part of JS standards, actually only whatwg retroactively wrote a standard, based on the current implementations. From the JS point of view, all (?) `console` does is to provide void methods.

Comment: @nopole - I should also note that regardless of whether TC39 "should" have defined `toString` for `Map` and `Set` in terms of their contents (I don't think they should, but that doesn't matter), they can't do so retroactively now. There's basically nothing more important to TC39 than backward compatibility (not "breaking the web"), and there could well be code written in the last five years that relies on getting `"[object Map]"` and `"[object Set]"` back from `toString` on Maps and Sets.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so I am wondering what `console.log()` uses, if any. Knowing and confirming what is good OOP and practices definitively helps, for us to know what it should be or could be vs what it is.

Comment: @nopole - The only way to know for sure, for a particular implementation, is to look at the implementation's source. Thankfully, most of these are open source. Unfortunately, they can be quite hard to read for people who don't already know the project. :-) But for instance, Node.js's console seems to look at what the own, enumerable properties of an object are and dump them out. (I remember being surprised recently that non-enumerable properties weren't included; they are in most consoles.)

Answer (score 4):

`console.log()`, along with other `console` methods, is implementation-dependent.

My answer applies only to Node.js.

---

After some looking into the internal source files of Node.js, it turned out that in Node (v12), `console` methods use a common way to display values: the `util.formatWithOptions` method.

Its internal source is written in JavaScript, and it calls internal formatter functions (located in `internal/util/inspect.js`), that formats objects based on their type, for example:

- Primitives are simply stringified.
- Plain objects are iterated over their properties, to show them.
- Arrays are iterated over based on their `length`.
- `Set` and `Map` objects' values are looked up using their iterators.

Answer (score 2):

The `console` is a host-provided object, and its implementation varies from host to host. Chrome's is different from Firefox's which is different from Node.js's which is different from... :-)

Typically, they check the type of what you're logging and then show whatever the implementer thought was a reasonable representation of what you logged. For objects and arrays, that usually involves querying the object/array for its contents (rather than calling `toString`) and showing a representation of those contents. (They may even query the contents using an internal feature of the JavaScript engine rather than going through the object's JavaScript-accessible API.) In "live" consoles like the ones in most browsers, the console even keeps a reference to the object so you can expand it and dive into its properties (details in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection)).

(At one stage, Node.js's console looked for a method on the object called `inspect` and used that, but that turned out to be problematic for objects where `inspect` wasn't meant to be used that way and was removed. As far as I know they haven't added that back using a Symbol-named method instead.)

Comment: yes, I understand in Chrome, it prints out something interactive, which is useful. But I think if it is a text based environment, then the `toString()` is actually what it is meant to be: a string representation in the text based environment.

Comment: @nopole - Well, you could raise an issue on the Node.js github (and other similar) if you want them to change it. But I doubt they will. I, for one, find the way they output things now handy, and wouldn't want all my generic objects output as `"[object Object]"`. :-)

Comment: maybe when the Web was evolving, they didn't want a string output of 1000 entries or dumping of the whole object property name and value because it was so slow back in 1995-2007, and also there can be infinite loops when dumping out an object this way when it has cyclic references. Maybe we can say, `console.log()` may be a debugging tool and it can afford to print out the whole thing, and `toString()` may not afford to. So in some language, it has `to_s` and `inspect` to print out different things... would it be to solve the issue of printing out the whole thing vs only a short version

Comment: @nopole - Yeah, that's what I was referring to with the note about Node.js not having added a Symbol-named method for this when (or after) they retired `inspect`. Would be handy. I wouldn't think TC39 would standardize one (they tend to stay away from that kind of thing), but I could see (for instance) a `Symbol.debugString` method being of some use...

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate specification for `console`, provided by WHATWG community: [Console Living Standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/).

When looking for `console.log` in that specification you get via the section [2.1 Logger](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) to the section [2.3 Printer](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer), which states:

> How the implementation prints *args* is up to the implementation, but implementations should separate the objects by a space or something similar, as that has become a developer expectation.

Typically, a console implementation will want to give a rich user interface, with expandable items, styling, allowing to drill down to the primitive values that build up the overall value. It does not have to be implemented in JavaScript, and calling `toString` may not be that handy any way, knowing that even `({ a: 1 }).toString()` returns `"[object Object]"`, which is not that useful.

Sometimes the given information goes beyond to what you could query synchronously in code, as is the case with promise objects. In the console the current state of such objects is output, while in code you need to at least call `then` (or do an `await`) to get that info.